# How to validate alphanumeric sender id for Twilio?

Tags: regex, sms, twilio, twilio-php

I am trying to figure out how can I validate an *alphanumeric* sender id for sending SMS via Twilio. I tried sending SMS with only numeric sender (not Twilio verified number, a random numeric sender id) and Twilio accepted that message. So I am not sure what exactly Twilio support in alphanumeric sender Id.

It would be helpful if Twilio API provides some Regular Expression for pattern matching or I could validate sender using API?

Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You will be able to find documentation about alphanumeric sender id's on the [What is Alphanumeric Sender ID and how do I get started?](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/what-is-alphanumeric-sender-id-and-how-do-i-get-started) page. Specifically, if you look under **What characters can I use as the sender ID?** you will find the following:

> You may use any combination of 1 to 11 letters, A-Z and numbers, 0-9.
>   Both lowercase and uppercase characters are supported as well as
>   spaces. 1 letter and no more than 11 alphanumeric characters may be
>   used.

A regular expression for this will vary depending on the programming language you're using, and in many cases you will find the language will have helpers for those things.

Also have a look at the [list of countries](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/what-countries-does-twilio-support-alphanumeric-sender-id) where this functionality is supported.

Depending on the language you're using, the following pattern should do what you want, but like I said before you may wanna add limitations to the string using your language of choice.

`/^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[a-zA-Z0-9])([a-zA-Z0-9 ]{1,11})$/m`

A live version can be seen [here](http://www.regexpal.com/?fam=94114).

Hope this helps you

Comment: This pattern excepts numeric string. It validates a number like "123456789", which if you use with Twilio.. Twilio will give you an error.

Comment: You're right. Updated my answer with that test case too

Comment: This does the job.. I want to ask anyway, so dash (-) is not allowed inside SMS Alphanumeric sender id?

Answer (score 1):

stumbled on this and found that twilio is now accepting more characters, I have this regex in the app im working on.

`^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9 +-_&]{1,11})$`

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer appears to be out-of-date here - Twilio's documentation at https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/services/api/alphasender-resource#alphasender-properties currently states:

> An Alphanumeric Sender ID string, up to 11 characters. Valid characters are A-Z, a-z, 0-9, space and dash ( - ). An Alphanumeric Sender ID string cannot be comprised of only numbers.

By that definition, I believe this would be a more appropriate regex:

`/^(?=.*[a-zA-Z \-])([a-zA-Z0-9 \-]{1,11})$/gm`